# Why do I have errors when build c code with Xcode?

Tags: xcode, gcc

I have code, that compile with `gcc`

```
gcc --version
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

without errors
But in Xcode I have errors. For example:

```
error build: Undefined symbol: _element_from_bytes_compressed
```

Comment: You'll need to give more details. You have most likely missed something in the config in Xcode.

Comment: what a details? i give if you say

Comment: details of Xcode project. what is included, you probably left something out.